# libGDX how to draw a rectangle in an InputProcessor

Tags: java, libgdx

What is the proper way to use the InputProcessor to draw a shape with the ShapeRenderer because usually I create it in the Render thread but the InputProcessor runs before the Render so it gets erased from the render thread.

For example

```
render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//draw rectangle if mouse clicked
}
```

(^^^ does work)
vs 
(does not work)

```
render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//???
}
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
//draw rectangle
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right, don't put rendering into an InputProcessor. Have a boolean variable to remember the clicked state. Set clicked to true on down and false on up. Then in your render method check the clicked state and if true then draw.

Comment: @StevenTrigg that sounds about right, was just having a brain freeze here, feel like I am adding more code than is necessary and was wanting to see an example of a way that is concise and acceptable.

Comment: You shold always try to sepperate logic and view. The `InputProcessor` should only create a `Rectangle` object, while the `render` should only draw it.